# Error compiling MATLink on Linux: /bin/ld: cannot find -luuid

Tags: matlab, matlink

Specifically how do you get a successful compilation of mengine? I tried the following:

```
sudo make -f Makefile.lin64
```

and got the following output:

```
g++ -O -Wall -I/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/../extern/include -L/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/../bin/glnxa64 menginetm.cpp mengine.cpp set.cpp get.cpp main.cpp -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/../bin/glnxa64/ -DMLINTERFACE=3 -lML64i3 -luuid -lmx -leng -o mengine
set.cpp: In function ‘void eng_make_String(const short unsigned int*, int)’:
set.cpp:160:31: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘len’ from ‘int’ to ‘mwSize {aka long unsigned int}’ inside { } is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]
     mwSize mbDims[2] = {1, len};
                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/cassert:43:0,
                 from set.cpp:13:
set.cpp: In function ‘void eng_make_Struct()’:
set.cpp:192:39: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     assert(mxGetNumberOfElements(var) == len);
                                       ^
/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.lin64:21: recipe for target 'mengine' failed
make: *** [mengine] Error 1
```

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Don't use `sudo` for this, it should not be necessary.  Even though in this case I could see what was wrong without additional information, please always give the following information with future requests: MATLAB version, Linux distro & version, gcc version, and the output of ``MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[]``.

Answer (score 1):

When something goes wrong with MATLink, the first thing to do is to go to its troubleshooting page:

- http://matlink.org/troubleshooting/

There, under the Linux heading, you'll find a reminder of the basic requirements for MATLink to compile/work.  Among them,

> - Ensure that development libraries for `libuuid` are installed. On Ubuntu, use `apt-get install uuid-dev`

---

Additionally (just in case this comes up later), it is important to use a C compiler compatible with your version of MATLAB.  The compiler requirements are listed by MathWorks for each MATLAB version.  You'll find them [here](https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016b/index.html?sec=glnxa64) for R2016b (click "Linux" at the top): it is gcc 4.9.x.  For [R2016a](https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016a/index.html?sec=glnxa64) it is gcc 4.8.x.  Older gcc will not work.